# Installing packages on Mac OS X

Tags: ros, macbook, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I install ROS package on Mac OS X?

This is the command used on Ubuntu system:

> sudo apt-get install ros-jade-gmapping ros-jade-amcl ros-jade-map-server ros-jade-move-base ros-jade-rviz ros-jade-navigation

How can I install the same packages on my Mac machine?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228917/installing-packages-on-mac-os-x/) by [dash](https://answers.ros.org/users/26257/dash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To install ROS on OSX, you'll have to build things from source. See the [Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source) for instructions.

A good alternative manual / installation procedure is Mike Purvis' [ros-install-osx](https://github.com/mikepurvis/ros-install-osx) (it basically does the same thing, but a bit more automated).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dash](https://answers.ros.org/users/26257/dash/) on 2016-03-13**:
I already have ROS installed. I just need to install additional packages. I don't have `apt-get` on Mac.